# How can I Rotate and scale at the same time (both together) in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resize, corel-draw

In Corel Draw when you double-click on objects and press shift key, you can do rotate and scale both together. and if you repeat this action you can make some parametric design. 
how can I do this function in illustrator?

Comment: Can you show an example of what you are trying to achieve please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there is a way to do it using the bounding box (drag and resize).

---

There is a way to do it manually by entering in the rotation and transform fields using:

**Object → Transform → Transform Each** (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) you will get a dialog with all the transform options:

[image]

You can then choose (fill out) the scale and the rotation fields and it will apply to it the object.

Answer (score 0):

Hold down shift to constrain the object and and grab the corners of the object to enlarge and or rotate.